# Capistrano log level

Tags: logging, capistrano, capistrano3, sshkit

I've set my Capistrano configuration's log level to `error` to prevent verbose output. In `deploy.rb` I've added `set :log_level, :error`. This works great. However, when I run commands via `execute`, it isn't printed as it's being written under the log level of `DEBUG`. How can I get the output of `execute` commands to be printed out? I am able to use `capture` with the combination of `puts` to output it, but this doesn't help when I have to stream the logs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this by defining the following method in your deploy.rb file:

```ruby
def with_verbosity(verbosity_level)
  old_verbosity = SSHKit.config.output_verbosity
  begin
    SSHKit.config.output_verbosity = verbosity_level
    yield
  ensure
    SSHKit.config.output_verbosity = old_verbosity
  end
end
```

Then simply call it like this:

```ruby
with_verbosity(Logger::DEBUG) do
  execute "./blah.sh"
end
```