# Capistrano 3 useless error message

Tags: npm, capistrano, sshkit

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with this command when run via a capistrano task. It runs fine if i run it directly on the server:

```
desc 'Run npm install on remote server'
  task :npm_install do
    on roles(:app) do
      puts '**** NPM INSTALL ****'
      execute "cd /var/www/#{fetch(:application)}/current/hapi && NODE_ENV=#{fetch(:env)} npm install"
    end
  end
```

Error which doesn't help much

```
$ cap prod deploy:npm_install
**** NPM INSTALL ****
INFO [23ed2aa2] Running /usr/bin/env cd /var/www/myapp/current/hapi && NODE_ENV=prod npm install as myuser@123.456.789.101
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as myuser@123.456.789.101: cd /var/www/myapp/current/hapi && NODE_ENV=prod npm install exit status: 1
cd /var/www/myapp/current/hapi && NODE_ENV=prod npm install stdout: Nothing written
cd /var/www/myapp/current/hapi && NODE_ENV=prod npm install stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: cd /var/www/myapp/current/hapi && NODE_ENV=prod npm install exit status: 1
cd /var/www/myapp/current/hapi && NODE_ENV=prod npm install stdout: Nothing written
cd /var/www/myapp/current/hapi && NODE_ENV=prod npm install stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:npm_install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Is there any way to turn on helpful error messages or something for remote tasks running through capistrano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog post](http://webtonio.com/capistrano-sshkitrunnerexecuteerror/) or this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977225/capistrano-log-level?rq=1) should help you increase your debugging.

This [FAQ](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/) should help you understand why Capistrano acts differently than a normal SSH session.