# How to get rake output to show in Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, capistrano

I am running rake tasks on the server using a snippet like the following in the deploy.rb of a rails app.

```
  desc 'Invoke rake task on the server'
  task :invoke do
    fail 'no task provided' unless ENV['task']

    on roles(:app) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :rake, ENV['task']
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The rake task runs ok but I would like to see the output from the rake task displayed in the console where I run the capistrano task.

puts commands in the rake task do not appear.

Comment: I just found that it depends on the server. On my staging server there is no output returned whereas on my production server there is output ...

Answer (score 0):

If in Debug mode, capistrano prints out the outputs of the commands if I'm not mistaken. Probably you set your log level to `:info`. Just find the line in your deploy.rb and change it to (add it if its not there):

```
set :log_level, :debug
```

If you want to have this only for the single command or I was wrong and the above solution does not work for you, maybe checkout this answer (dunno if its still working):
[Capistrano log level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977225/capistrano-log-level)

UPDATE: How about using Rails logger instead of puts in the game task:

```
Rails.logger.debug "test"
```

Comment: It is already in debug mode but no output is shown from rake. Interestingly the output from dB:migrate IS shown .

Comment: have you tried the second solution that is linked in my answer. Looks quite similar to what you need.

Comment: Makes no difference the capistrano log level is already set to debug. I tried it out of interest but it made no difference. I do get an output saying the rake task is run "DEBUG [4b23c943]  Rake test run at 2015-08-21 12:43:08 +1200" but not the output from my "put" statements in the rake task.